# neighbor analysis in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, neighbours

I have an m-by-n matrix named A, with values 1s and 0s. I want to convert all 0s values to 1s if at least 5 out of 8 neighbor pixels are 1s. What I tried is to use the `nlfilter` function, but I'm not getting how the arg `fun` should be used, and I would need a help.
I created a function as handle for `nlfilter` as following:

```
function b = gap_fill(A)
b=A;
index= A([1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9]);
if sum(index)>=5
b(5)= 1
end
end
```

Then I tried to do this:

```
B= nlfilter(A,[3 3],@gap_fill)
```

But it gave this error:

```
??? Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ==> nlfilter at 75
    b(i,j) = feval(fun,x,params{:});
```

Any suggestion? The main problem is I'm not used to handle functions.

= UPDATING =

I finally came up with a good result. I changed my function to output a scalar and when I use it as `fun` arg in `nlfilter` it work the way I want. This is my code, thanks for helping and I hope it could be useful for anybody:

```
function b = gap_fill(A)
index= A([1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9]);
if sum(index)>=5
A(5)= 1;
end
b=A(5);
end
```

In MATLAB:

```
b= nlfilter (A,[3 3],'gap_fill')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one line with [`blockproc`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/images/ref/blockproc.html):

```
B = blockproc(A,[1 1],@(x)sum(x.data(:)),'BorderSize',[1 1],'TrimBorder',0)-A>=5;
```

For example,

```
A =

     1     0     1     1     0
     0     0     0     1     1
     1     1     1     1     1
     0     1     0     1     1
```

gives the result

```
B =

     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     1     0
     0     0     1     1     1
     0     0     1     0     0
```

Note that border pixels of the image are handled correctly, thanks to using the `'BorderSize'` option of `blockproc`.

To keep the original ones in `A`, apply a final "or" operation:

```
B = B|A;
```

Comment: I would need to avoid converting 1s to 0s, as in B of your example

Comment: @umbe1987 Apply a final "or" operation: `B = B|A;` (see updated answer)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because the documentation for `nlfilter` says that the user function must return a scalar and you are trying to return a matrix.

```
B = nlfilter(A, [m n], fun) applies the function fun to each m-by-n sliding block 
of the grayscale image A. fun is a function that accepts an m-by-n matrix as input
and returns a scalar (!!!) result.
```

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that's slightly faster than `blockproc`, you can use a 2D convolution:

```
mask = ones(3);
mask(5) = 0;
B = conv2(A,mask,'same') >= 5;
```

To make this even faster (you'll only notice this if the arrays become larger), you can make use of the fact that an average filter is separable:

```
B = conv2(conv2(A,ones(1,3),'same'),ones(3,1),'same') - A >= 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

The fun function must return an scalar in your case it returns a matrix. from matlab

B = nlfilter(A, [m n], fun) applies the function fun to each m-by-n sliding block of the grayscale image A. fun is a function that accepts an m-by-n matrix as input and returns a scalar result.

```
c = fun(x)
```

so your code shoud be There are better ways to code it,specially with amtrix but following your sample:

```
function b = gap_fill(A)
index= A([1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9]);
if A(5)sum(index)>=5
    b = 1;
else
    b = A(5);
end
end
```

Sorry for the error I change b = 0 to b= A(5)

Comment: Unfortunately, this code converts also some 1s to 0s, and I have to avoid it.

Comment: Yes that's true, i forget to check if it was allready a one, I will edit it